# Storing and accessing Object position vector

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have a class `Object`, which has a `vec3` attribute to store its position

```
class Object{
public:
  Object();
  ~Object();
  glm::vec3 position;
  virtual float getX();  //these methods get the x, y and z value of the vec3 position
  virtual float getY();
  virtual float getZ();

private:
};
```

Then I have a class `Linker`, which would "link" `Objects`, based on their positions.

```
class Linker
{
    Object *obj;
public:
    Linker(Object *obj);
    virtual void link(Object *o);  //this method should perform actions based on Object position
};
```

In my `main.cpp` I create few `Objects` and I'm storing them in a `std::vector`

```
static vector<unique_ptr<Object>> allObj;
static vector<Linker> allLinkers;

unique_ptr<Object> createNewObj(int x, int y, int z) {
    unique_ptr<Object> obj(new Object());
    obj->position(vec3(x, y, z));
    return obj;
    }

void createPattern()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
        {
             allObj.push_back(createNewObj(x, 1.0f, z));
        }
    }

    for (auto &p : allObj) {
        Linker lnkr = Linker(p);
        //EDIT
        allLinkers.push_back(lnkr);
    }
}

void linkPattern()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allObj.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        auto p = allObj[i+1];    //this is where my problem comes up
        allLinkers[i].link(p);   //takes the linker of the first object and "links" it with the second
    }
}
```

The nested loop in `createPattern()` creates a grid of `Objects`. I would like to link `Objects` based on their position, and not only `allObj[i+1]`, but I would like to be able to `link` the `Object` with `vec3 position = <0.0, 1.0, 0.0>` like:

[image: Grid of Objects]

And I would like to do the same with every other `Object` and its neighbours.

My loop creates really few `Objects` at the moment, but I probably need to create a huge amount of them later.

In this case, is `std::vector` the best way to store `Objects`?
Is there a way to store them so I can directly access them by their position?

Comment: From what i understand you want an efficient way to find the object at a certain position?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to be able to say like: link obj to object x+1, z+1 and so on..

Comment: The easiest way that is still very efficient that comes to mind would be a std::map. Use the position as key and object as value. However, if you do not have a sparse grid(every position contains an object) you can just use a multidimensional array.

Comment: I tried with a 2D array, but I get errors and I find difficult to perform other actions on my Objects.

Comment: Elaborate on the errors? And if you find it difficult to perforn other actions, specify what they are so we have more restrictions to the data structure design.

Comment: Honestly, the code is huge and this is a really simplified concept of my core problem. I think an std::map could work as well.

Comment: Read an answer I've posted. Easiest solution for you would be to create your own container with custom access methods.

Comment: I've read your answer, I'm still trying to understand it and how I can use that Grid

Comment: I'll add an more complete code with implementation into your code to demosntrate usage.

Comment: I'm also getting two errors: 1) a reference of type "Object &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::unique_ptr<Object, std::default_delete<Object>>"   2)no suitable user-defined conversion from "const std::unique_ptr<Object, std::default_delete<Object>>" to "const Object" exists

Comment: his code was missing dereference opeators for unique_ptr, I fixed it, try it again

Comment: @MarošBeťko yes please!!

Comment: Ok I've written what I could with the information that you provided. So I have a few questions: Do you intend to use all the positions of said grid so that on every position there would be an Object? What exactly will linker link now that you can access these objects by their X/Y/Z? What are you exactly inserting when you call createNewObject?

Comment: 1) I still don't know, honestly. 2) linker performs physics calculations on the 2 objects it is considering. 3) createNewObject just creates a new Object with the position I pass as arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was dealing with similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950262/custom-data-structures-with-various-access-methods). I also wrote an answer on how I solved my problem. So basically I've created my own container consisting of multiple private ones, which you can access by pubic methods. In my case these being overloaded operator() for a direct X/Y access. In your case the base structure holding your data would be compound vector of unique pointers and for direct access you can make overloaded `operator()(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z)` that would look something like this:

```
class Grid {
public:
   Object& operator()(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z) noexcept {
      return *_data[z][y][x];
   }

   // same method returning const reference(read-only)
   const Object& operator()(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z) const noexcept {
      return *_data[z][y][x];
   }

   /* Safer but throws std::out_of_range exception, which you should handle
   Object& operator()(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z) {
      return *_data.at(z).at(y).at(z);
   }
   */
private:
   vector<vector<vector<unique_ptr<Object> > > > _data;
}
```

This way you can directly give the Linker objects by their X/Y/Z position. Hope this solves your problem.

P.S.: Instead of `vector<vector<vector...` you could use simple `vector<unique_ptr<Object>>` but in that case for operator() you would return something like `_data[x + y * width + z * height * width]` but I'm not quite sure if this it the right formula for object from 3D matrix on pos x/y/z. For 2D matrix it would be `_data[x + y * width]`

EDIT: Implementation:

```
class Grid {
public:
   // Constructor fills the Grid with Objects created from theirs default constructor
   Grid(unsigned width, unsigned height, unsigned depth)
      : _width(width), _height(height), _depth(depth) {
      _data.resize(depth);
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
         _data[i].resize(height);
         for (unsigned j = 0; i < height; ++i)
            _data[i][j].push_back(make_unique<Object>()); 
            // Calls a consturctor of Object
            // If you don't plan on filling every single position you can instead fill it with nullptr to save memory
      }
   }

   Object& operator()(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z) {
      return *_data[z][y][x];
   }

   unsigned size() { return _width * _height * _depth; }    
   unsigned width() { return _width; }    
   unsigned height() { return _height; }    
   unsigned depth() { return _depth; }

private:
   vector<vector<vector<unique_ptr<Object> > > > _data;
   unsigned _width;
   unsigned _height;
   unsigned _depth;
}

static Grid allObj(width, height, depth);
static vector<Linker> allLinkers;

unique_ptr<Object> createNewObj(int x, int y, int z) {
    unique_ptr<Object> obj(new Object());
    obj->position(vec3(x, y, z));
    return obj;
    }

void createPattern()
{
    // no need for inserting because Objects are created on allObj creation

    // changed the iterator based range for to normal for loops
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < allObj.depth - 1; ++k)
       for (unsigned j = 0; j < allObj.height - 1; ++j)
          for (unsigned i = 0; i < allObj.width - 1; ++i)
             Linker.push_back({ allObj(i, j, k) });
}
```

While writing this I've realized that I don't really know what exactly your linker does and what is the purpose of linking the i-th object with (i+1)-th object and how it will translate to getting them by X/Y/Z and not a single index.

EDIT2: If you want to link these object like the image shows then the linking process would look something like this:

```
for (unsigned k = 0; k < allObj.depth - 1; ++k)
   for (unsigned j = 0; j < allObj.height - 1; ++j)
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < allObj.width - 1; ++i) {
         auto p = allObj(i + 1, j, k);
         allLinkers[i].link(p);
         p = allObj(i, j + 1, k);
         allLinkers[i].link(p);
         p = allObj(i, j, k + 1);
         allLinkers[i].link(p);
         // and continue with whatever else you want to link
         // as you can see this is quite unefective so maybe modifying link method
         // so it takes no parameters and automatically links all neighbouring objects would be better
      }
```

This will link every object to its directly neighbouring objects. So for example object at 3/4/5 will be linked to 4/4/5, 3/5/5 and 3/4/6.

EDIT3: Simplified the program structure. Placed all functionality into to Grid class. Here is the code:

```
class Grid {
public:
    // Create a grid with set width, height and depth
    Grid(unsigned width, unsigned height, unsigned depth)
            : _width(width), _height(height), _depth(depth) {

        // This replaces the createPattern function
        // Creates both objects and linkers
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            _objects.push_back(make_unique<Object>());
            _linkers.push_back({ _objects[i].get() });
        }

        // This replaces the linkPattern function
        // Does the linking exactly as shown on the picture
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            _linkers[i].link(&object(_objects[i]->getX(), _objects[i]->getY(), _objects[i]->getZ() + 1));
            _linkers[i].link(&object(_objects[i]->() + 1, _objects[i]->getY(), _objects[i]->getZ()));
            _linkers[i].link(&object(_objects[i]->getX() + 1, _objects[i]->getY(), _objects[i]->getZ() + 1));
        }
    }

    // Direct access operator
    Object& object(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z) noexcept {
        return *_objects[x + y * _width + z * _height * _width];
    }

    // another possible implementation of Direct access operator
    // checks if element you want is 'in range'
    // NOTE: may throw std::out_of_range
    const Object& operator()(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z) const {
        size_t position = x + y * _width + z * _height * _width;
        if (position >= _objects.size() || x > _width || y > _height || z > _depth)
            throw std::out_of_range("index is out of range");
        return *_objects[x + y * _width + z * _height * _width];
    }

    // Direct access for linkers
    Linker& linker(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z) noexcept {
        return _linkers[x + y * _width + z * _height * _width];
    }

    // Getters
    constexpr unsigned size() const noexcept { return _width * _height * _depth; }
    constexpr unsigned width() const noexcept { return _width; }
    constexpr unsigned height() const noexcept { return _height; }
    constexpr unsigned depth() const noexcept { return _depth; }

    // Iterators - using ranged for would loop throught all the Objects from _objects

    using iterator = std::vector<unique_ptr<Object> >::iterator;
    using const_iterator = std::vector<unique_ptr<Object> >::const_iterator;
    using reverse_iterator = std::vector<unique_ptr<Object> >::reverse_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::vector<unique_ptr<Object> >::const_reverse_iterator;

    iterator begin() noexcept { return _objects.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return _objects.begin(); }

    iterator end() noexcept { return _objects.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const noexcept { return _objects.end(); }

    reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept { return _objects.rbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept { return _objects.rbegin(); }

    reverse_iterator rend() noexcept { return _objects.rend(); }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept { return _objects.rend(); }

private:
    vector<Linker> _linkers;
    vector<unique_ptr<Object> > _objects;
    const unsigned _width;
    const unsigned _height;
    const unsigned _depth;
};
```

And this would be the usage of said class doing everything your code samples do:

```
// The grid containing all the objects and linkers
Grid allObj(3, 1, 3);

// You can access objects like this
allObj.object(x, y, z);

// or like this (returns const& (read-only))
allObj(x, y, z);

// Likewise the linker
allObj.linker(x, y, z);
```

Comment: as well you might use at() for vectors, instead of operator[]. at() checks if you are within range of vector, thus it is safer.

Comment: Linker performs physics calculation on the object. The second part of your "question", about how it will translate to get them by X, Y, Z it is actually my problem

Comment: How can I complete the method insert()?

Comment: completed it c:

Comment: why in Linker.push_back({ allObj(i, j, k) }); Linker is called in that way?

Comment: And also, that's true that objects are created on allObj creation, but I need to call createNewObject to create the objects.

Comment: @Koosshh56 that's the same as what your code did. Writing it like this means that an temporary object created with parameters inside {} will be created and then moved into the vector.

Comment: i added insert method but op meanwhile changed post... Getters should be const qualified tho. operator() should be overloaded to return const Object& as well

Comment: @MarošBeťko I'm so sorry, I've just noticed that I made a mistake in my code in that part. I'm pushing back into the list of allLinkers. See the edit, please

Comment: @Koosshh56 yes that makes sence, I haven't even noticed that. You are referencing to some Pattern in your function names. Is it some class you are using? If not can't you make Grid your pattern and make the create/insertPattern functions it's methods? Also then linker could also be a part of the Grid.

Comment: Pattern isn't a class, it is just the way I call grid.

Comment: by the way, why are getters in Objects and Linker::link virtual?

Comment: because those classes are in an header and I implement them in a .cpp

Comment: it doesn't mean they need to be virtual then, Virtual functions are used in inheritance. If you don't plan on inheriting from Object virtual only slows your program. And if you want virtual methods, destructor should be virtual as well.

Comment: @Koosshh56 Chek out the last edit. Does this solve what you were having problems with? Also if you need the create/linkPattern functions to be separate you can leave Grid constructor empty and split it's content into two functions.